# Laravel URLs with query parameters

Tags: laravel, url-routing, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I want to implement a link in my application, but instead of it following this format:

> /origin/{number}

I want it to look like this:

> /origin=number

How do I implement a route successfully which will understand this link format? Surely Laravel is flexible enough to not only be able to parse slash-based URLs?

Comment: `Route::get('/origin={number}', ...);`? The title is also a little misleading as query parameters come after `?`.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer for future reference. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
Route::get('/origin={number}', ...);
```